# Shrink width of the wrapped text block and align vertically with the next sibling

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to get the following with CSS only?

1. The *Container* is of fixed width (say 200px),
2. The *Text block* should wrap only when required,
3. Both *Text block* and *Query mark* are vertically aligned, even when the text is wrapped,
4. The *Text block* occupies only required width (by default, when wrap occurs the block occupies the whole width),
5. The *Query mark* follows immediately (don't align right)

In the sample below, lines 1 and 3 are OK, the text in line 2 should not be wrapped when it is not required to fit (it caused by `width: 1px` workaround)

Maybe you know ready solutions for the required layout?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milichev/Lzcrbq2p/)

```css
.tbl {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1em;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: .2em;
}

/* set the container width explicitly */
.cell:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 200px;
}

.wrap {
  padding: .2em;
  /* the following aligns both child vertically */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  background: #efefef;
  /* the following makes the element to shrink its width */
  display: inline-table;
  width: 1px;
}

.help {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 0 .2em;
}

.help:after {
  content: '?';
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">1</td>
    <td class="cell">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="text">Active</div>
        <div class="help" title="Active"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">2</td>
    <td class="cell">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="text">Is an AVM</div>
        <div class="help" title="Is an AVM"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">3</td>
    <td class="cell">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="text">Uploadable by CRM/Investigations</div>
        <div class="help" title="Uploadable by CRM/Investigations"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```